# JUnit5 test with bad data type

Tags: java, types, junit5

In order to learn JUnit test cases
I want to write a simple JUnit5 test case and i get
an error

My class

1 easy class

```
public class Med {

    private String name;
    private double price;    
    private int stock;

    public Med(String p_name,double p_price,int p_stock) {
        this.name = p_name;
        this.price = p_price;
        this.stock = p_stock;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("med name: " + this.getName() + ", med price: " + this.price + ", stock: " + this.getStock());
    }

}
```

my method into my main

1 easy method

```
public static void f05DisplayStocks(Med[] p_arrMeds) {

    System.out.println("f05DisplayStock");
    System.out.println("stocks state");

    for (Med med:p_arrMeds) {

        System.out.println(med.getName() + ", " + med.getStock());
    }

}
```

My test

an easy JUnit5 test

```
class TestPharmacie {
        public Pharmacie ph01 = new Pharmacie();

    @Test
    public void testF05DisplayStocks() {

          // ACT: Vars

          Med med01 = new Med("medName01", 1.0, 1);
          Med med02 = new Med("medName02", 2.0, 2);

          Med [] meds = new Med[2];

          meds[0] = med01;
          meds[1] = med02;

         // ARRANGE

         // ASSERT
         assertEquals(1, Pharmacie.f05DisplayStocks(meds[0].getStock()));

    }
}
```

the problem is into JUnit test, last line (// ASSERT section)
here the error msg

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method f05DisplayStocks(Med[]) in the type Pharmacie is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

I don't know how to fix my test

Advices..?

Thank you

RR

[EDIT]
Hi, i read your comments and answer and made changes into Pharmacie class and JUnit test case:
Below changes:

Pharmacie class

```
public class Pharmacie {
    
    private static Med[]  med = new Med[2];
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        med[0] = new Med("Aspiron", 20.40, 4);
        med[1] = new Med("Rhinoplexil",19.15, 5);
        
        f05DisplayStocks(med);
        
    }

    public static int f05DisplayStocks(Med[] p_arrMeds) {

        // System.out.println("f05DisplayStock");
        // System.out.println("stocks state");

        for (Med med:p_arrMeds) {

            // System.out.println(med.getName() + ", " + med.getStock());
            
        }
        
        // System.out.println(med[0].getStock());
        return med[0].getStock();

    }
    
}
```

ant the JUnit test

```
class TestMed {
    
    public Pharmacie ph01 = new Pharmacie();
    public Med med01 = new Med("medName01", 1.0, 1);
    public Med med02 = new Med("medName02", 2.0, 2);
    public Med [] meds = new Med[] {med01, med02};
    
    @Test
    public void testF05DisplayStocks() {
    
        // ACT: Vars
        
        // ARRANGE
        
        // ASSERT
        System.out.println(meds[0].getStock());
        
        // will send a NullPointerException cause:
        // java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.pharmacie02.Med.getStock()" because "org.pharmacie02.Pharmacie.med[0]" is null
        // --> assertEquals(1, Pharmacie.f05DisplayStocks(meds));
        
        // will send the fist error:
        // The method f05DisplayStocks(Med[]) in the type Pharmacie is not applicable for the arguments (int)
        // --> assertEquals(1, Pharmacie.f05DisplayStocks(meds[0].getStock()));
    
    }
    
}
```

According to these both syntaxes i get the same error or another, different i'm not able to understand either.

i think you understood i'm newbie, so thank you for your patience and your knowledge.
RR

Comment: `meds[0].getStock()` does not return a `Med []`. But the parameter that `f05DisplayStocks()` takes is a `Med []`. Are you sure you need to call `getStock()` there and not just use `meds[0]`?

Comment: the assertEquals is expecting an int value =1 as response, but f05DisplayStocks is void type (it doesn't return any value)

Comment: thank you for your comments and the answer. i just edited my answer according what you told me but not able to resolve my problem. You can see my changes below [EDIT] tag. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, assertEquals method checks whether the first parameter, **1** ,  is equal to the second parameter,  **Pharmacie.f05DisplayStocks(meds[0].getStock())**
However, the return type of the function  f05DisplayStocks is **void**, so it cannot be compared with the integer 1 in the first parameter of the assertEquals.

Secondly, I also see that you have defined  f05DisplayStocks to take in as parameter an array of Med, but in the ASSERT section of the code you are passing it only meds[0].getStock()), an int value and not the whole array